# AngularJS service to store SEO metadata

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, seo

I'm followed this tutorial and tried to use the service for dynamic seo metadata.
https://weluse.de/blog/angularjs-seo-finally-a-piece-of-cake.html

However, run into an issue - Seems like the service is not accessable outside of controller's view. `<div ui-view></div>`

Here is the service i'm trying to implement:

```
app.service('SeoMetaService', function() {

        var metaDescription = '';
        var metaKeywords = '';
        var title = '';
        return {
            metaDescription: function() { return metaDescription; },
            metaKeywords: function() { return metaKeywords; },
            title: function() { return title; },

            reset: function() {
                metaDescription = '';
                metaKeywords = '';
                title = '';
            },
            setMetaDescription: function(newMetaDescription) {
                metaDescription = newMetaDescription;
            },
            appendMetaKeywords: function(newKeywords) {
                for(var i=0;i<newKeywords.length;i++){
                        if (metaKeywords === '') {
                            metaKeywords += newKeywords[i];
                        } else {
                            metaKeywords += ', ' + newKeywords[i];
                        }
                }
            },
            setTitle: function(newTitle) { title = newTitle; }
        };
    });
```

usage in controller:

```
app.controller('WelcomeController',['$scope', 'SeoMetaService', function($scope, SeoMetaService) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    var keywords = ["bla bla","bla bla blah"];
    SeoMetaService.setTitle("title bla bla bla");
    SeoMetaService.setMetaDescription("description bla bla bla");
    SeoMetaService.appendMetaKeywords(keywords);

    console.log(SeoMetaService.metaDescription());
    console.log(SeoMetaService.metaKeywords());
});
}]);
```

on the main page (one-page-app), simplified:

```
<html ng-app="MainPage">
<head>
    <title>{{SeoMetaService.title()}}</title>

    <meta name="description" content="{{ SeoMetaService.metaDescription() }}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ SeoMetaService.metaKeywords() }}">
    <base href="/">
</head>

<body>
 <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

So the **problem is** - i thought that angular services are singletons.
But, after running the controller and setting the data, it doesn't appear in HTML.

How to fix/what to do?

Comment: Don't use jQuery (`$(document).ready()`) inside an Angular controller. You don't need it, and you should not interact with the DOM in any way within a controller.

Comment: Why not ? i use sometimes.

Comment: What for? The document *will* be ready by the time the controller executes, so it's superfluous. And you shall not manipulate the DOM from controllers, because then you're back to writing jQuery mush. One of Angular's core strengths is the rigorous separation into services/controllers/views, which makes your app much more modular and maintainable if you do it right. Once you start writing halfway complex applications and you need to grow and modify them, you'll quickly hit ugly spots when tying a controller to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that you defined the `WelcomeController` at level of View.

So `SeoMetaService` is visible only in the inner html present in the `<div ui-view></div>`.

You need to define the controller `WelcomeController` at level of `<html>` or `<head>`, because `SeoMetaService` is accessible only inside the tag defining the controller `WelcomeController`.

Additionally you need to remove the reference to `JQuery` and expose the `SeoMetaService` in the `$scope`.

The code should be something like that.

The HTML:

```
<head ng-controller='WelcomeController'>
<title>{{SeoMetaService.title()}}</title>

    <meta name="description" content="{{ SeoMetaService.metaDescription() }}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ SeoMetaService.metaKeywords() }}">
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

The controller updated:

```
app.controller('WelcomeController',['$scope', 'SeoMetaService', function($scope, SeoMetaService) {

    var keywords = ["bla bla","bla bla blah"];
    SeoMetaService.setTitle("title bla bla bla");
    SeoMetaService.setMetaDescription("description bla bla bla");
    SeoMetaService.appendMetaKeywords(keywords);

    console.log(SeoMetaService.metaDescription());
    console.log(SeoMetaService.metaKeywords());

    // Added to the scope SeoMetaService
    $scope.SeoMetaService = SeoMetaService;


}]);
```

Note that you can change the content of SeoMetaService also in another controller, so for example changing a view you can update title, meta description and meta keywords reflecting the content of the new view.
Here is a possible example for the controller `MyViewController`

```
app.controller('MyViewController',['$scope', 'SeoMetaService', function($scope, SeoMetaService) {

    var keywords = ["xxx","yyy"];
    SeoMetaService.setTitle("title my view");
    SeoMetaService.setMetaDescription("description my view");
    SeoMetaService.appendMetaKeywords(keywords);

}]);
```

When you enter the view using the controller `MyViewController` the keywords, title, meta description and meta keywords will be updated.

Comment: The service is also not exposed on the controller or scope in any way, so this by itself won't help much…

Comment: @deceze you are right. I added also SeoMetaService to the $scope in th example

Comment: So, as i understood, i need to create a controller  for `<head>` to declare the `SeoMetaService` in it, and then i'll be able to modify it from the controllers which are within the `<body>` tag, right?

Comment: @user1935987 yes You are right. A service as you said is a singleton so you can change values from any controller and that changes are visible everywhere. In the WelcomeController you can eventually only expose the SeoMetaService.

Comment: seems like for some reason `<head ng-controller='HeadMetaController'>` this controller declaration isn't working for me. i also use ui-router.
Controller is just not initialized

Comment: Check if the javascript containing the controller is correctly loaded, that "app" is correctly initialized, that the javascript containing SeoMetaService is correctly loaded. Check also that there are no javascript errors.

Comment: yep, controller and service are definitely loaded ok. i see them in resources. and all injectors are good. no errors, just seems like `ng-controller` not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121596/discussion-between-davide-lorenzo-marino-and-user1935987).

Comment: fix your answer pls, `ng-controller='WelcomeController'` on `<head>` tag is not working, i guess for Angular 1.3+